# How to hide ANSI colour escape codes from fmt

Tags: colors, ansi-escape

I use (GNU) `fmt` to format longer texts with nice (‘optimal’) line breaks. However, if the text contains any ANSI colour escape sequences (which are never displayed, and only serve to colour the text when displaying it), `fmt` considers these as normal characters, and calculates the wrong line lengths.

I’m not sure how good literal escape characters work here, so here’s a simple example using `grep` to generate the ANSI sequences. Let’s start with a long string to format.

```
string="Here’s an example of a rather long \
string with quite a few words in the middle \
that grep chooses to colour red."
```

If we don’t highlight the `grep` matches, everything works fine:

```
echo $string | grep --color=no i | fmt -w 50
```

But if we highlight/colour them, `fmt` considers the lines containing the letter ‘i’ to be much longer than they really are, and they are shown as rather short lines when displayed in a terminal.

```
echo $string | grep --color=yes i | fmt -w 50
```

Is there a way to avoid this? For this example I could of course use `fmt` *before* `grep`, but when the search string spans several words, this doesn’t work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to resolve that using grep and fmt. I recommend you run fmt first and then use sed instead of grep for searching. For example:

```
echo The search string will be highlighted red. | fmt -w 50 | sed ":a;$!N;$!ba;s/search[ \n]string/\x1b\[1;31m&\x1b\[0m/g"
```

Comment: Thanks. That’s the solution I ended up using.

My real-world use of this actually involves `sed` instead of `grep`. Basically, I convert tags (such as `|` in `this is an |example| string`) to ANSI colour sequences to colour the words they span. Using `fmt` before the replacing isn’t optimal, since the tags do take up some space, which affects the word wrapping, but it’s not too bad unless a line contains very many such tags, and it’s better than running `fmt` after replacing (as the ANSI escape sequences take up many more characters).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hmt](https://github.com/rolfschr/hmt) for this. It was conceived exactly for this scenario.

Note: I am the author of `hmt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep --colour=auto' instead would solve the problem.

Comment: No, it wouldn’t. Using `grep --colour=auto` has the same result as using `grep --colour=no` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Abandon `fmt` and use a GNU `sed` script instead:

### **`afmt.sed`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sed -Enf

:0
# insert break after 79 visible characters (skipping ANSI sequences)
s/^((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*[^\x1B]){79}(\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~]|[[:blank:]])*/\0\n/
# if line isn't long enough to be broken, skip to end
Tx

# if break was inserted mid-word, move it to preceding opportunity   
s/^(((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*.)+([[:blank:]]|[^[:blank:]]-))(.*)\n/\1\n\5/m

# trim trailing blanks, moving embedded ANSI sequences onto continuation line
:1
s/[[:blank:]]+((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*)\n/\n\1/
t1

# print finished line
P

# scrub ANSI sequences from leading indentation
:2
s/^([[:blank:]]*)(\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])+/\1/
t2

# delete finished line, keeping indentation for continuation line
s/^([[:blank:]]*).*\n/\1/m

# loop to process continuation line
t0

:x
p
```

### Features

- Breaks lines after a blank or hyphen where possible, but will break a long first word on a line if unavoidable.
- Trims trailing blanks from wrapped lines, moving onto the continuation line any ANSI sequences that were embedded in the trailing run of blanks.
- Copies leading indentation (scrubbed of any embedded ANSI sequences) onto continuation lines.
- Treats tabulation characters as having width 1, so you may want to pipe your text through `expand` first if it might contain tabs.

### Bash Alias

You can make it an alias in your `~/.bashrc`, taking advantage of Bash's automatic `$COLUMNS` variable to adapt the output to the width of your terminal:

```bash
alias afmt='sed -Ene '\'':0;s/^((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*[^\x1B]){'\''"$((${COLUMNS:-80}-1))"'\''}(\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~]|[[:blank:]])*/\0\n/;Tx;s/^(((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*.)+([[:blank:]]|[^[:blank:]]-))(.*)\n/\1\n\5/m;:1;s/[[:blank:]]+((\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])*)\n/\n\1/;t1;P;:2;s/^([[:blank:]]*)(\x1B\[[ -?]*[@-~])+/\1/;t2;s/^([[:blank:]]*).*\n/\1/m;t0;:x;p'\'
```

### Example

After setting the Bash alias as shown above,

```bash
string="Here’s an example of a rather long \
string with quite a few words in the middle \
that grep chooses to colour red."

echo $string | grep --color=no  i | ( COLUMNS=50 ; afmt )
echo $string | grep --color=yes i | ( COLUMNS=50 ; afmt )
```

`afmt` yields the same wrapping regardless of grep's coloring.

### Fancier Demo ;)

```bash
N=( {seven,six,fif,for,thir,twen}ty{-{nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one},}$'\e[m columns of chars' )
x=' on the screen'
for (( i = 0 ; i < 59 ; ++i )) ; do
  { printf "\n%${i}s"
    echo -e "\e[92;1m${N[i]@u}$x, \e[93;1m${N[i]}. " \
      "You splice one off and pipe it to groff; \e[91;1m${N[i+1]}$x."
  } | sed -Enf afmt.sed
done
```